# como puedo seguir con la ejecución de script y que no se me pare en un punto?

Tags: powershell

cuando el script llega a $objeto.convertmedia(...) se queda en ejecución y no pasa ha mostrar el texto write-host hasta que termina como puedo hacer para que $objeto.convertmedia(...) se ejecute en segundo plano y siga el script ejecutandose y me muestre write-host "ejecutando"

```
 cls


  $objeto = New-Object NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter


  $proceso = Get-Process -name ffmpeg

  cls



  $input = Get-Item "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\javi.mp4"

  $output = "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\juas"

  $objeto.ConvertMedia($input,$output + ".mp3", "mp3")  ##aquí se me para no 
                                                        #ejecuta lo de abajo 
                                                        #hasta que no termina 
                                                        #el proceso

  write-host "ejecutando"
```

Comment: y si ejecutás el write-host primero? Porque PowerShell corre línea a línea...

Comment: eso si  pero lo que me esta haciendo que pensar y bastante es como calcular el tiempo del proceso convert media para luego convertirlo en una barra de proceso